# Getting the following Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:{“method”:”xpath”,”selector”:”//span[@id=’lblError’]/text()”}”

Tags: python, xml, xpath

My xpath:

```
//span[@id=’lblError’]/text()
```

works correctly in developer tools in Chrome. When I use the same xpath in python 2.7 [image: I use the same xpath in python 2.7]  I get the following error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element {“method”:”xpath”,”selector”:”//span[@id=’lblError’]/text()”}”

In Python 2.7 my xpath is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(“//span[@id=’lblError’]/text()”)
```

Also if I use `("//span[@id=’lblError’]")` it does not work as well.

Also I am using python 2.7 with selenium webdriver.

Comment: Are you sure the page has finished rendering? Are you sure the element isn't in an iframe? What have you done to try to debug this? If it can't find `//span[@id='lblError']`, I think it's fair to assume it won't find anything with that xpath and additional components on the xpath, so you first need to solve the problem of locating `//span[@id='lblError']`,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include text() in the XPath expression, separate it.

You can try the below option:

> element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='lblError']");
>
> print element.text

If the above option doesn't work then try to give some delay before fetching it.